# something similar to palindrome in python

Tags: python

The following strings are considered valid:
Strings which do not contain any of the following characters: `['/', '<', '>']`
If s is valid , then so is `'<t>' + s + '</t>'`, where t is one of the following the
strings: `'B', 'I', 'U', 'BIG', 'SMALL'`. These "tags" specify any special formatting for
the text between them (bold, indent underline, increased font size, decreased font size,
respectively)
consumes a string s,and produce true if s is valid false otherwise.

```
def valid_cs116_html(s):
    if '/' or '<' or'>' not in s:
        return True
```

i only worte down the base case which is not containing `['/', '<', '>']`,how do i determine the second case `'<t>' + s + '</t>'`?

Comment: Did you test `if '/' or '<' or'>' not in s:` ? My gut tells me that isn't doing what you think it is.

Comment: So this is [assignment 7 q3](https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs116/Assignments/a07/a07.pdf). I guess you didn't read about [academic integrity](https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs116/integrity): *"If you find yourself stuck, contact the tutor or instructor for help, instead of getting the solution from someone else."*

Comment: valid_cs116_html sounds an awful lot like a homework function :)

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's funny, I saw Q1 on that assignment asked here a few days ago too.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the string starts and ends with `<t>` and `</t>`, respectively (for each of your valid `t`s). If it does, strip those tags and return `valid_cs116_html(s)` where `s` is the 'inner' string as in your description.

Also, this:

```
if '/' or '<' or'>' not in s:
```

doesn't do what you think it does. You'll need:

```
if '/' not in s and '<' not in s and '>' not in s:
```

or even:

```
if not any(c in s for c in ('/', '<', '>')):
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do here is check if the beginning and ending of the string have matching tags. We can use Python's [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) library to match against those tags, and then check whether the rest of the string is valid:

```
def valid_cs116_html(s):
    match = re.match(r'^<(B|I|U|BIG|SMALL)>(.*?)</\1>$', s)
    if match is not None:
        return valid_cs116_html(match.group(2))
    else:
        return all(c not in s for c in '/<>')
```

Comment: @AdamSmith Are you saying that string fails for my code?

Comment: Sheesh, comment deleted. I don't know where my mind is today but it's apparently not a good day to code! :) I got hung up on OP's comment of "palindromes" and though if there was leading but not trailing whitespace (or vice versa) that Bad Things would happen. That's completely irrelevant, SORRY! However `<B><I>text</I></B>` does fail, which is probably not great.